# preparedStatement.executeUpdate() did not return a value larger than 0

Tags: java, jdbc

When i insert the datas in the form and submit it, no error is returned, but when i check my database i found that the same infos that i had before remained the same and nothing changed and the message "No user was updated " pops up on the console.

I tried checking my database fields and servlet but i still can't find the problem.
here is what happens when i modify my form :

(ID 7  NOM doe PRENOM jhon AGE 25 PASSWORD jhon123 EMAIL jhon@gmail.com IDROLE 2 User updated successfully!)

So where is the problem please ?

Here is the DAO :

```
 private static final String Update_user = "UPDATE utilisateur SET 
 idutilisateur = ? ,nom = ? ,prenom=?  , age = ?,email = ? , mot_de_pass = ? , idrole = ?"
            + " WHERE  idutilisateur = ?";
    `public static void updateUser(Utilisateurs u) throws SQLException {
        try (Connection connection = Conx();
             PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(Update_user)) {

            preparedStatement.setInt(1, u.getIdUtilisateurs());
            preparedStatement.setString(2, u.getNom());
            preparedStatement.setString(3, u.getPrenom());
            preparedStatement.setInt(4, u.getAge());
            preparedStatement.setString(5, u.getEmail());
            preparedStatement.setString(6, u.getPassword());
            preparedStatement.setInt(7, u.getRole().getIdRole());
            preparedStatement.setInt(8, u.getIdUtilisateurs());

            int rowsUpdated = preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

            if (rowsUpdated > 0) {
                connection.commit(); 
                System.out.println("User updated successfully!");
            } else {
                System.out.println("No user was updated.");
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

---

```java
protected static Connection Conx() {
    Connection connection = null;
    String jdbcURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/gestion_ecommerce";
    String username = "root";
    String pw = "";
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcURL, username, pw);
        System.out.println("connection ok");
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return connection;
}
```

Comment: Is that backtick in front of `public` and `protected` a typo here or a typo in your code?

Comment: By the way, variable names begin with a lowercase letter. And, `Utilisateurs` should be singular, `Utilisateur`.

Comment: Dump the contents of `Utilisateurs` object passed to `updateUser` method to verify you do indeed have changed data in hand.

Comment: that backtick is just a typo when i copied it to stackoverflow. it doest exist in my code,  and i didnt understand the third comment, how would i dupm the contents of `Utilisateurs` object ?

Comment: when i try dumping the contents of `Utilisateurs` object , i see on the console that all the informations are updated. but why arent it updated in the database ?

Comment: Your code isn't sufficient to just know it, it depends on what `Conx` does and your database engine. But, wild stab in dark? You have to `connection.commit()` or the transaction is aborted when the connection object is closed.

Comment: i've added `connection.commit()` in the if block. And for the `conx` i'm using mysql connector. Here is the code for the Conx :  protected static Connection Conx() {
  Connection connection = null;
  String jdbcURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/gestion_ecommerce";
  String username = "root";
  String pw = "";
  
  try {
   Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"); 
    connection  = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcURL, username, pw);
   System.out.println("connection ok");
  }
  catch(Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  } 
  return connection;
 }

Comment: Method names start with a lowercase letter, per Java conventions.

Comment: Column `idutilisateur` appears in both the SET clause and the WHERE clause of your UPDATE statement. This seems strange to me. I'm only guessing but this may cause problems. I think you need to remove `idutilisateur` from the SET clause. Also, you wrote (in your question): _when i check my database i found that the same infos that i had before remained the same and nothing changed_ How did you check? Maybe your check is the wrong way to check. By the way, it is no longer required to call `Class.forName` in order to register the JDBC driver.